# AWS Windows EC2 File Transfer - Need to keep session open

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, chocolatey

I have a rather large file that I need to copy from an S3 bucket to a Windows EC2 and it will not complete before a session ends. I have found lots of suggestions for this for Linux but not Windows.

The few things that I have seen recommend using screen and to install the screen package from chocolatey (choco install screen), which I tried but it's tell me that the package can't be found.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else to try to keep a file transfer running even if the session is terminated?

Comment: What *"session"* are you referring to?